# Cant use declare or temp table in SQL view, suggestions please

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms, sqlclr, sql-view

I have a requirement to create a view in SQL 2012, the script runs in SSMS as standalone but needs converting to a view, however the script utilises a CLR to generate the key data.  So to date we have been putting the CLR outcome into a temp table and joining from there.  As temp tables aren't allowed in a view, we have resorted to using a variable for the table instead, but that is throwing an error around the declare part.  We have obviously tried to run it as a stored proc, but cant call that from a view...Any suggestions would be appreciated.

This is the working code

```
 declare @idList IdList
 INSERT INTO @idList SELECT distinct RT_ID FROM [RT]
 DECLARE @CLRs TABLE (
 RT_ID nvarchar(19)
,rowindex nvarchar(20)
,Exp1 nvarchar(20)
,Exp2 nvarchar(20)   )

INSERT INTO @CLRs
SELECT [IDLIST].[id] as RT_ID
,AD.ROWINDEX
,dbo.fnPropercase(Contact) as Exp1
,dbo.fnPropercase(Contact2) as Exp2
from @idList [IDLIST]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [CLR DETAILS](@idList,1) [AD] on [IDLIST].[id] = [AD].RT_ID
INNER JOIN CONTACTS CS on CS.CONTACTS_ID= AD.RT_CONT_ID
SELECT * FROM @CLRs
```

Obviously this is a simplified script but the intention is still there to see

Thankyou.

Comment: Something seems off here. What exactly is the SQLCLR TVF doing? Is it really SQLCLR? It looks as though `@idList` is a User-Defined Table Type but you can't pass those into SQLCLR objects. Is the query above truly the working code, or has it been altered for the purpose of posting to a public site? As it is, this is very confusing code, especially due to most of the object and field names being meaningless. And is there really a space in the object name `[CLR DETAILS]`? If so, you should consider removing that as it will be much easier to work with if there is no space.

Answer (score 1):

CTEs are the answer.

```
WITH 
    IdList AS (SELECT distinct RT_ID FROM [RT]),
    CLRs AS (SELECT [IDLIST].[id] AS RT_ID
                    ,AD.ROWINDEX
                    ,dbo.fnPropercase(Contact) AS Exp1
                    ,dbo.fnPropercase(Contact2) AS Exp2
             FROM IdList [IDLIST]
             LEFT OUTER JOIN [CLR DETAILS](IdList,1) [AD] 
                 ON [IDLIST].[id] = [AD].RT_ID
             INNER JOIN CONTACTS CS 
                 ON CS.CONTACTS_ID = AD.RT_CONT_ID)
    SELECT * FROM CLRs
```

The above should be your view definition. As you mentioned that this is a simplified case, feel free to add more `CTE`s and JOIN them as you wish!

Documentation: [MDSN - CTEs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Thankyou for your time @freakyhat, yes, CTE's have been the answer!